# How can I be notified when my boyfriend tracks my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, privacy

I would like to know how often my boyfriend checks where I am. Is it possible to be notified when he checks on me? In the country where I live, Find My Friends is not available.

Comment: How does he check the location ? Using find my iPhone or using Find my friends ?

Comment: Maybe you ought to change your iCloud password...

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately no,

Find My Friend is a one way communication style app. It allows you to notify people of your location and see their location. Also, you have the ability to notify someone when you arrive, leave a place, or you can send your current location. You can also be notified if someone lease or arrives at a place (and they can do the same), however it does not have the ability to notify you if someone requested your location.